# Google Sheets: Change text color of cells in other columns if specific cell is focused?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a sheet with four columns.

What I would like to do is the following:

If the cursor is inside a cell in column A (meaning that cell is focused), the cells of that row from the other three columns should change their text color.

**Example:**

Cursor is focused on cell A1. Cells B1, C1 and D1 should change their text color from white to black.

The same would apply to A2 and so on.

Can this be achieved by conditional formatting or a script?